# R mutate ( ".data" is missing, with no default)

Tags: r, dplyr

I wrote this function in R

```
match <- followers %>%
  +   mutate(x= ifelse(followers$screen_name %in% xnames$screen_name, 1, 0),y= ifelse(followers$screen_name %in% ynames$screen_name,   1, 0))
```

but i get this error and i can't solve it

```
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

here more information about the data

```
  > str(xnames)
    'data.frame':   5000 obs. of  1 variable:
     $ screen_name: chr  "27khT5dIkDpu4hl" "M8ibrahem" "IBRAHEM87711" "ryooon85" ...
    > str(ynames)
    'data.frame':   5000 obs. of  1 variable:
     $ screen_name: chr  "rosebiose" "S7q0QTdIk8SLcNm" "DleGQquoaUGxQzn" "RxafjLONGO6UgS8" ...
str(followers)
'data.frame':   9925 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ screen_name: chr  "27khT5dIkDpu4hl" "M8ibrahem" "IBRAHEM87711" "ryooon85" ...
```

here is sample of the data

```
    > head(xnames)
          screen_name
    1 27khT5dIkDpu4hl
    2       M8ibrahem
    3    IBRAHEM87711
    4        ryooon85
    5        sqrr1233
    6          3ram16

> head(ynames)
      screen_name
1       rosebiose
2 S7q0QTdIk8SLcNm
3 DleGQquoaUGxQzn
4 RxafjLONGO6UgS8
5 YlirzqF0N9EfeOY
6      AL_3GEEEED

> head(followers)
      screen_name
1 27khT5dIkDpu4hl
2       M8ibrahem
3    IBRAHEM87711
4        ryooon85
5        sqrr1233
6          3ram16
```

I tried also to convert the type of the columns to factor but still gives me the same error

thank you

Comment: Could you add some data to make your code reproducible? Also, in `dplyr`, it should be useless `followers$`, if you are working with `followers` data in the chain (the other are ok because you are calling vectors that are not in the `followers` data).

Comment: You can't have the dollar sign in the pipe `df %>%...mutate(df**$**...)`

Comment: Sotos : I use it with small data set and its work

Comment: s_t : I update the question

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution with fake data, I advice you to use also `dplyr::if_else` rather than `ifelse`, it's safer:

```
library(dplyr)
followers <- data.frame(screen_name = c(' 27khT5dIkDpu4hl','M8ibrahem','IBRAHEM87711','ryooon85','sqrr1233','3ram16'))
xnames <- data.frame(screen_name = c('27khT5dIkDpu4hl','IBRAHEM87711','ryooon85','sqrr1233','3ram16'))
ynames <- data.frame(screen_name = c('rosebiose','S7q0QTdIk8SLcNm','DleGQquoaUGxQzn','RxafjLONGO6UgS8','YlirzqF0N9EfeOY','AL_3GEEEED'))


followers %>% mutate(x = if_else(screen_name %in% xnames$screen_name,1,0),
                     y = if_else(screen_name %in% ynames$screen_name,1,0))
       screen_name x y
1  27khT5dIkDpu4hl 0 0
2        M8ibrahem 0 0
3     IBRAHEM87711 1 0
4         ryooon85 1 0
5         sqrr1233 1 0
6           3ram16 1 0
```

Comment: Error in screen_name %in% xnames$screen_name : 
  object 'screen_name' not found

Comment: @FatimaAlbusayyis ,edited with your data, and it seems there was a typo.

Comment: yes when i tried it with your example it works, but when i tried it with whole data set gives me the same error and i am sure that my code is correct

Comment: Maybe you have to fits the columns' names, it's difficult to know without the data that creates the problem. Does it's the correct answer or you need further modifications?